# Advantages to formulating the Collatz Conjecture without division?

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture

Usually, the Collatz function is defined by $C(n)=3n+1$ if $n$ is odd, and $C(n)=\frac{n}{2}$ if $n$ is even. The famous conjecture states that some iterate of $C$ evaluated at $n$ is $1$, for any positive integer $n$.

I've spent a lot of time playing around with this problem, and one thing I've noticed is that the "division by 2" step doesn't seem too crucial to whatever mysterious mechanism governs this behavior.

Specifically, we can reformulate the conjecture (equivalently) without division:

> Define $C(n)$ to equal $3n+2^k$, where $k$ is the smallest exponent occurring in the base-2 expansion of the (positive integer) input $n$.
>
> Now, no matter which $n$ we start with, the sequence $C(n),C^2(n),\ldots$ eventually reaches a power of 2.

This is essentially the same as the usual formulation, in which we divide by 2 until the "$k$" value is just zero. (We still must reach a power of 2 before getting to 1.)

Perhaps this version is less convenient computationally since the sequence values get larger and larger. On the other hand, the statement seems, at least notationally, more streamlined.

I'm just wondering if there are other apparent advantages (or disadvantages) to stating the conjecture in this way.

Also, I would appreciate any references to this particular formulation.

Comment: I'd say that *is* piecewise, and worse - it has infinitely many pieces (per the values of $k$) instead of just two.

Comment: That's definitely true. Still, given that the Collatz iteration is usually characterized as a "hailstone" sequence, it's interesting to me that it can be formulated in a "strictly increasing" manner. It's as if the "up and down" behavior is a sort of red herring...

Comment: There is no advantage, and no disadvantage with your method. When we measure distances, we can choose to count meters or kilometers, or millimeters, it is exactlty similar. Here, you suggest something similar : you choose to continue to count in millimeters, even when you know that all numbers are 'exact multiples of 1000' and you could count in meters or kilometers with integers.

Comment: One can get that non-division by 2 in a "computable function". Then you study the bit additions or subtractions of borrow bit. You'll see local behaviour and maybe this nim-sum can prove the conjecture. I like both representations. One is more suited for mathematicians and I guess the other is more suited for computer scientists...

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, you can express the Collatz algorithm without division (although fractions look nicer). Here's just one way to do it to generate odd-only sequences:

If $n+1$ is divisible by $4$, multiply by $1.5$, subtract $1$

If $n-1$ is divisible by $8$, multiply by $0.75$, add $1$

Else multiply $n-1$ by $0.25$

Stated as a somewhat clunky function:

$f(n) = \begin{cases} ((n+1)*1.5)-1) & \mbox{if } n+1 \equiv 0 \mbox{ (mod } 4) \\ ((n-1)*0.75)+1) & \mbox{if } n-1 \equiv 0 \mbox{ (mod } 8)  \\ (n-1) * 0.25 & \mbox{if } n-1 \equiv 4 \mbox{ (mod } 8)\end{cases}$

Of course, the distinction between decimal fractions and division is nonexistent. However, this reveals the "hidden" bijection - all integers of  the form $8n+5: f(n−1)\frac{1}{4}$ - that produces superset odd numbers.

One reason for this alternative statement of the conjecture is clarity. The even numbers may be fruitfully dismissed as ornaments - although an even-only proof is also possible.